# Use of the _PARTITIONDATE vs. the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo-columns in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In the official best-practices I [found](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs):

> Partitioning your tables by date and querying the relevant partition; for example, WHERE _PARTITIONDATE="2017-01-01" only scans the January 1, 2017 partition

And I started using the `_PARTITIONDATE` pseudo-column quite a lot, as I find it easier to write queries this way, in contrast to the `_PARTITIONTIME` column and applying a `TIMESTAMP()` function onto my date, like shown in this [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables):

> WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28')

I was wondering if I should continue with my usage of `_PARTITIONDATE` - as I was unable to find any more documentation on it. Also, in contrast to `_PARTITIONTIME` it does not get syntax-highlighted in the web-based BigQuery SQL-editor.

Is the official way to favor `_PARTITIONTIME` over `_PARTTIONDATE`?

Comment: As of 2021 May, [Best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) document contains `WHERE _PARTITIONDATE="2017-01-01"` now and there is also `_PARTITIONTIME` mentioned.  It is confusing but I guess they can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_PARTITIONDATE` isn't documented, because it doesn't correspond to a feature that has been released. You should use `_PARTITIONTIME` unless we announce a new feature in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes).

```
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2016-03-28')
```

is exactly the same as

```
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = '2016-03-28'
```

The `_PARTITIONTIME` column is a timestamp, so the string literal on the right side of the latter example is coerced to a timestamp. In terms of syntax highlighting, the current UI has some limitations of recognizing built-in functions, but an upcoming UI refresh is expected to address that.

Comment: You mention two times `_PARTITIONTIME`, but I guess you meant `_PARTITIONDATE` in your second line?

I know that they are semantically the same, I just wanted to make sure not to use something not officially supported to avoid that the column might go away in the future. (So my question was regarding `_PARTITIONDATE` vs. `_PARTITIONTIME`)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see what you mean. `_PARTITIONDATE` isn't documented because it doesn't correspond to a feature that has been released. You should use `_PARTITIONTIME` unless we announce a new feature in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I've updated your answer so that it's easier for people to get the info without reading the comments! I guess that the [Best-Practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) should be updated then to use `_PARTITIONTIME`?

Comment: While I can't find it in the release notes, `_PARTITIONDATE` is by now documented, so it should be safe to use.