# Partition pruning for bigquery partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query using analytic function for a day partitioned table. I would expect it to read only data in partitions filtered in where clause but it reads all partitions in the table.

```
WITH query AS (
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(rank)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day order by num_mean_temp_samples) AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONDATE) AS day,
      *
    FROM
      `mydataset.gsod_partitioned` ) q_nested
  ) q
WHERE
  rank < 1000
)
SELECT
  num_mean_temp_samples ,
  count(1) as samples
FROM query
 WHERE
   day in ( '20100101', '20100103')
GROUP BY  1 ORDER BY 1
```

I verified partition pruning works without analytic function:

```
WITH query AS (
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONDATE) AS day,
  *
FROM
  `mydataset.gsod_partitioned`
)
```

or after adding  UNION ALL nested select:

```
WITH query AS (
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(rank)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day order by num_mean_temp_samples) AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONDATE) AS day,
      *
    FROM
      `mydataset.gsod_partitioned` WHERE _PARTITIONDATE < "1970-01-01" ) q_nested1
  UNION ALL SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day order by num_mean_temp_samples) AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONDATE) AS day,
      *
    FROM
      `mydataset.gsod_partitioned` WHERE _PARTITIONDATE >= "1970-01-01" ) q_nested2
  ) q
WHERE
  rank < 1000
)
```

Table mydataset.gsod_partitioned is public dataset gsod based where day=20100101 partition is created as follows:

```
bq query --destination_table 'private.gsod_partitioned$20100101' --time_partitioning_type=DAY --use_legacy_sql=false
'SELECT station_number, mean_temp, num_mean_temp_samples FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod` where year=2010 and month=01 and day=01'
```

Could you find a way to enable partition pruning for the analytic function without adding extra union to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding _PARTITIONDATE - it isn't documented feature and it is recommended to use _PARTITIONETIME instead, you could look for some other question to see one of Googlers saying about that: [Use of the _PARTITIONDATE vs. the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo-columns in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175073/use-of-the-partitiondate-vs-the-partitiontime-pseudo-columns-in-bigquery)

Regarding **partition pruning with analitycal functions** in last year Google added support for filter pushdown but is **works only for _PARTITIONTIME** which should be included in fields covered by PARTITON BY clause

It should look like this:

```
WITH query AS (
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(rank)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY _pt order by num_mean_temp_samples) AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONTIME) AS day,
      _PARTITIONTIME as _pt,
      *
    FROM
      `mydataset.gsod_partitioned` ) q_nested
  ) q
WHERE
  rank < 1000
)
SELECT
  num_mean_temp_samples ,
  count(1) as samples
FROM query
 WHERE
   day in ( '20100101', '20100103')
GROUP BY  1 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I verified that changing _PARTITIONDATE -> _PARTITIONTIME with FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONTIME) function doesn't prune partitions too. Using _PARTITIONDATE or _PARTITIONTIME without formatting enables partition pruning but I need to have day formatted.

Comment: I see your point. Pleas look at added code, it should work for you

Comment: That's nice workaround, but still thinking it should work with formatted day, shouldn't it?

Comment: yeah, it would be great to have it working like that but I wouldn't consider it as a bug. For me it qualifies for feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149 Maybe someone from BigQuery team will response to your suggestion here.

Comment: It seems like the predicate "day in ( '20100101', '20100103')" is not pushed down so partitions are not pruned. In the UNION ALL version, you put the predicate right with the table, _PARTITIONDATE < "1970-01-01", so no push down is needed. I guess D.M.'s answer somehow got around this problem. Please file a bug/feature request as D.M. suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Reported as suggested: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537225 Thank you.